# What kind of framework I should use to build a MSAccess-like Python web site?

Tags: python, web-development, framework, mvc, rad

I need to build a web site with framework that let me build a skeleton with index, security with login(email recovery), style, and then add forms for CRUD, list, views, maps, landing pages, export DB, import DB, responsive, connectivity to MySQl and MongoDB.
If is the MVC the desired architecture as well as a SPA:
What kind of framework will help me from beginning ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Django has built-in admin which provides auto-generated for creating and editing model instances. You can also create forms. You can create landing pages with Django Flatpages (and other libraries). It supports MySQL and also MongoDB to a lesser extent. It also has built-in authentication with email recovery.